# Retrieve emails for user within the application

Tags: iphone, ios, gmail

My application requires me to retrieve gmail emails for the user within the application. How do I go about doing that? To be specific I am looking for some code/api for authenticating the user against gmail servers, and retrieving the response in xml/json. I've seen people do that in other applications, wonder how they do it.

Comment: The [API page](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/) has both an Atom feed and IMAP access. Which one are you trying to use?

Comment: @Rup: Yep, you're right. Deleted the dup comment, but can't undo the close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, there is no such API from google for gmail. I've decided to use IMAP client in iphone to work it out.